# C++ Aligned Array or vector of "unsigned long" on 64-byte boundary, and associated delete[]

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, memory-alignment

I have tried

```
unsigned long* ulongsArray = new(std::align_val_t{ 64 }) unsigned long[1024];
delete[] ulongsArray;
// ::operator delete[](ulongsArray, std::align_val_t{ 64 });   // same compiler error
// ::operator delete[](new(std::align_val_t{ 64 }) unsigned long[1024], std::align_val_t{ 64 });   // same compiler error
```

but, under VisualStudio 2019 get an error "error C2956: usual deallocation function 'void operator delete[](void *,std::align_val_t) noexcept' would be chosen as placement deallocation function." which seems to point to the C++17 standard lacking definition for the delete[] of aligned arrays.

VisualStudio2019 seems to align on 64-byte boundaries by default, along with Intel Compiler. However, g++ seems to align to 16-byte boundaries, and I need 64-byte alignment (cache line).

Comment: We've been having a bit of a fight with C++ over-aligned memory recently!  We build for Mac (ARM and Intel) and Windows.  I think in the end we had to have different calls for different platforms.    This might be useful? https://github.com/NickStrupat/AlignedMalloc

Comment: I've been unable to reproduce this on Godbolt using gcc trunk and clang trunk. E.g. https://godbolt.org/z/ebdhrPde6 . However, I do get that error when using MSVC latest. Might be specific to compiler implementation then?

Comment: JCx - Does your implementation of aligned_malloc and free coexist with C++ new and delete[]? Quite a bit of my code is using new and delete[].

Comment: C2P1 - I tried the first alternate delete[] implementation (using your provided link), which also compiled under gcc without errors. This seems like a better match to the aligned new version. Wonder if one of them is the correct one to use, and if either cause memory leaks.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be an issue with the MSVC compiler as it compiles fine with gcc and clang. It's been reported in the past [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/using-c17-new-stdalign-val-tn-syntax-results-in-er/528320)

However, the intended result you are looking for can be achieved (across each of MSVC, clang, and GCC) by doing the following instead:

```cpp
unsigned long *ulongsArray = static_cast<unsigned long*>(
        operator new[](sizeof(unsigned long) * 64, (std::align_val_t)(64)));
delete[] ulongsArray;
```

Comment: The above compiles ok, but throws in the delete[]. The first alternate variant seems to work for the delete[], and aligns the array to 64-bytes. Thank you! This helped a lot. I will test this method for memory leaks and will report back.

Comment: Exception throwing is in MSVC (when using the delete[] used in the question) . g++ seems to run with either method: the delete[] used in the question, or the first alternate method (commented out).

Comment: @DragonSpit how about trying `alignas(64)` instead? Depending on what you are looking for you could have: `alignas(64) unsigned long ulongsArray[64];`

Comment: Sadly, I need allocation on the heap, with a dynamic value. alignas would work nicely for for allocating fixed amounts on the stack, and is much better than using __declspec() method.